# why is FPGA suited for Cryptography applications?

Tags: hash, aes, sha-256

FPGA is suited for acceleration of algorithms that can be pipelined, or for network acceleration (in-line processing).

Why is FPGA suited for cryptography / security applications? For example AES, SHA... what features of those workloads makes then adequate for FPGA?

Comment: Half joking: FPGA is adequate when [full-custom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit#Full-custom_design) is desirable, but one can't afford the [NRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-recurring_engineering) and [TTM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_market); use a CPU, clever design and coding when even an FPGA can't be afforded. Also: modern x64 CPUs, and increasingly many others, have built-in support for AES, SHA-1, and SHA-256; such CPU will often exceed FPGA performance, almost always so if the bulk of the data flow is from/to that CPU for some reason.

Comment: @fgrieu As an answer to your "for some reason", we are basically bus constrained. http://degnan68k.blogspot.com/2015/04/assessing-trends-in-performance-per.html  If you have a dataflow application, the FPGA wins.  If you have data you can cache, the CPU wins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple. When you have a job to be done you choose toolkit which would accomplish it in a fastest possible way.CPUs are usually multi-tasked they would be running your OS beside running your cryptographic toolkit. Also, colloquially speaking, FPGA circuits can be designed for partcilar sort of computaion *in hardware* reaching a far higher efficiency in terms of energy utilization and performace.

So it is not that FPGAs have some special features that CPUs lack. Its just a matter of specialization in circuits construction for a specific task. ex. SHA.